# PHP/Javascript Form Reset upon page entry or back

Tags: php, javascript

I have a standard PHP form that has a series of checkboxes, radio, selects and text.  The form works fine and proceeds to a search results page.  My problem is that when you click Back browser in any browser the search page shows the previous selects.  How do I ensure that the back button displays the form as if its the first time the visitor visits the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset form on `window.onload` or $(document).ready(for jQuery)

```
function formReset()
{
       document.getElementById("formId").reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing.

Using jquery onReady function you can make form reset.

So, whenever user will press back button of browser page will be reload and onReady function your code for form reset will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').get(0).reset();

});
```

Comment: That does not seem to word for me when I search and then click back here it still saves the previous criteria in Step 2 and Step 3?  Sample: http://tinyurl.com/97nq6yt

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't reset it automatically. Provide a reset button.

The back button returns the user to the previous page, in the state he left it. This includes the settings of any form. I'm relying heavily on this feature, cannot count the times this back button saved me from loosing my efforts that went into a textbox for answering questions...

It's a different game if the user is on your result page and clicks a link that takes him to the search page **again**, but does not use the back button.